# Chromium Browser XFCE panel indicator

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce, chromium, xfce-panel

Google Chrome, when installed, presents an icon in the XFCE4 panel display under XUbuntu. Chromium does not. Is there anyway to install the panel indicator icon in XFCE for Chromium.

For Google Chrome, the panel indicator shows Google Chrome running in the background and makes available quick-launch buttons for the apps.

Comment: Could it be related to this chromium blog post?
https://blog.chromium.org/2016/03/retiring-chrome-app-launcher.html

Comment: Also please take a look at this:
https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

Comment: what linux distribution is this exactly and also is the desktop evironment (XFCE) manually installed or did it come with?

Comment: Xubuntu 17.04 . it Congress with xfce